# Incomplete \iffalse error in AMS alignment

Tags: amsmath, conditionals

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,xparse}
\makeatletter
\newif\ifinvd@lims\invd@limsfalse
\newif\iflr\lrfalse
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\delim}[3][lr]{
\begingroup
\str_case:nnF { #1 }
    {
    { lr }{\def\lsize{\left}\def\rsize{\right}    \lrtrue}
}
{\typeout{#1}
}
\str_case:nnF { #2 }
    {
    { v }{\def\ldel{|}\def\rdel{|}}
}
{\typeout{#2}
}
    \ifinvd@lims
        \ldel #3 \rdel
    \else
        \lsize\ldel #3 \rsize\rdel
    \fi
\endgroup
}
%\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand{\abs}[1][lr]{\delim[#1]{v}}

\begin{document}
\[\abs{Jh(x,y,z)}=\begingroup
\str_case:nnF {lr}
    {
    { lr }{\def\lsize{\left}\def\rsize{\right}    \lrtrue}
}
{\typeout{}
}
\str_case:nnF {v}
    {
    { v }{\def\ldel{|}\def\rdel{|}}
}
{\typeout{}
}
    \ifinvd@lims
%        \ldel #3 \rdel
    \else
        \lsize\ldel \begin{matrix}
y-z & x & -x \\
0 & 2(y+z) & 2(y+z) \\
2z & 4y & 4z
\end{matrix} \rsize\rdel
    \fi
\endgroup

\]
\begin{align*}
\abs{Jh(x,y,z)}=&\abs{\begin{matrix}
y-z & x & -x \\
0 & 2(y+z) & 2(y+z) \\
2z & 4y & 4z
\end{matrix}}=(y-z)\abs{\begin{matrix} 2(y+z) & 2(y+z) \\ 4y & 4z \end{matrix}}+{} \\
{}+&2x\abs{\begin{matrix} x & -x \\ 2(y+z) & 2(y+z) \end{matrix}}=4(y-z)(y+z)\abs{\begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\ y & z \end{matrix}}+4x^2(y-z)\abs{\begin{matrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{matrix}}=-8(y-z)^2(y+z)+8x^2(y+z)=8(y+z)(x^2-(y-z)^2\!).
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

This generates the error `Incomplete \iffalse: all text was ignored after line 64`, line 64 being the second `\end{align*}`. If I use an `align*` the first time too (i.e. where there is `\[…\]` in the code above), the error shifts to line 53 (`\end{matrix} \rsize\rdel`), and the incomplete if is and `\ifx`. If I use `\[…\]` the second time too, everything compiles, and I get:
[image]
which is what I want, save for the hyper-overfull \hbox, which is why I wanted the `align*` basically. So what is happening in here? Everything seems to be `align*`'s fault, though even a `gather*` gives the problem. Removing the stars also does nothing. How do I get this to compile?

Comment: you've been on the site long enough to know that really isn't a useful title for future archival purposes

Comment: You have to put `\makeatother` somewhere. Please minimize your code! You are talking about two aligns but show one. The error results in an other line number so this information does not help either. It is very difficult to understand your hole post.

Comment: I don't think anybody is willing to plunge into that messy code without even the slightest information about the expected result.

Comment: By the way, I'm that used to expl3 formatting that when I see expl3 *badly* formatted, I simply can't read it. I think it's nice to have a guideline to write code in a way that eases understanding.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi why should I "have to put `\makeatother` somewhere"? Is there any good reason why a document should not have @ as a letter outside the preamble, save for avoiding conflict with a package's internals? And besides, I need @ as a letter because of the conditional. As for the number of aligns, I hope the edit made things clearer. I don't think you would want to see three version of the same code with little edits which I can describe in words, right? How am I supposed to further reduce this? I have already cut it down a lot.

Comment: `.\@ foo` doesn't work if `@` is a letter.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle OK, but I only did this in a MWE where I didn't need that, so there is no point in telling me off for that, since I needed @ as a letter there. In other documents, I don't leave @ as letter, at least in principle, though I might forget to turn it back to other. Anyway, what is `.\@ foo`?

Comment: wasn't telling you off, just that you asked if it ever made a difference, the answer is almost always no except for `.\@` usage.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the "telling me off" part was referring to LaRiFaRi's comment, not yours. "that" meant "not using `\makeatother` in the code", and wasn't in any way related to `.\@`. Thx for the answer. But what _is_ this `.\@`?

Comment: @MickG see in chat, I just posted an example:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't given any indication of what this code is intended to do and it is a very bizarre mix of latex3, latex2e and tex primitives, so I haven't attempted to guess what it is doing, but this version runs without error.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,xparse}
\makeatletter
\newif\ifinvd@lims\invd@limsfalse
\newif\iflr\lrfalse
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\delim}[3][lr]{
\begingroup
\str_case:nnF { #1 }
    {
    { lr }{\def\lsize{\left}\def\rsize{\right}    \lrtrue}
}
{\typeout{#1}
}
\str_case:nnF { #2 }
    {
    { v }{\def\ldel{|}\def\rdel{|}}
}
{\typeout{#2}
}
    \ifinvd@lims
        \ldel #3 \rdel
    \else
        \lsize\ldel #3 \rsize\rdel
    \fi
\endgroup
}
%\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand{\abs}[1][lr]{\delim[#1]{v}}

\begin{document}
\[\abs{Jh(x,y,z)}=\begingroup
\str_case:nnF {lr}
    {
    { lr }{\def\lsize{\left}\def\rsize{\right}    \lrtrue}
}
{\typeout{}
}
\str_case:nnF {v}
    {
    { v }{\def\ldel{|}\def\rdel{|}}
}
{\typeout{}
}
    \ifinvd@lims
%        \ldel #3 \rdel
    \else
        \lsize\ldel \begin{matrix}
y-z & x & -x \\
0 & 2(y+z) & 2(y+z) \\
2z & 4y & 4z
\end{matrix} \rsize\rdel
    \fi
\endgroup

\]
\begin{align*}
{\abs{Jh(x,y,z)}}=&
{\abs{\begin{matrix}
y-z & x & -x \\
0 & 2(y+z) & 2(y+z) \\
2z & 4y & 4z
\end{matrix}}}=(y-z){\abs{\begin{matrix} 2(y+z) & 2(y+z) \\ 4y & 4z \end{matrix}}}+{} \\
{}+&2x
{\abs{\begin{matrix} x & -x \\ 2(y+z) & 2(y+z) \end{matrix}}}
=4(y-z)(y+z)
{\abs{\begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\ y & z \end{matrix}}}
+4x^2(y-z)
{\abs{\begin{matrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{matrix}}}
=-8(y-z)^2(y+z)+8x^2(y+z)=8(y+z)(x^2-(y-z)^2\!).
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The code is meant to define a flexible delimiter command (there are many more cases in the actual thing, for many size combinations and delimiter combinations, but I needed it to be minimal here) and then to use it in that equation with the align to solve the overfull \hbox and align as your version shows (plus another line change I will plug in afterwards). It defines `\abs` in terms of `\delim` too, for the sake of clarity and shortness. That equation was in the middle of my notes, but I extracted it to give an MWE. So the problem is solved. I wonder why grouping solved it…

Comment: `\ifinvd@lims` is defined to be used in `\delim` when using combinations such as ]…[, which need `\mathopen` and/or `\mathclose` which has to include the size command too, meaning I need to do `\ldel\rdel` and not `\lsize\ldel\rsize\rdel`, since the size is in the `\ldel\rdel` pair. The grouping inside the `\delim` command is to avoid the redefinition of those commands to be problematic in nested `\delims`: suppose I do `\pa{\abs{…}}`. The result without the `\begingroup…\endgroup` is (|…||. With it, it becomes (|…|), as wanted.

Comment: Any idea why the `{…}` you added around each `\abs` with `matrix` inside solved the error?

Comment: @MickG the error message implied you had the scopes wrong somewhere there was no way I was going to debug the code (really there must be a better way of doing whatever it is doing) so the first thing I tried was putting `{}` around each use. The error went away so I posted.

Comment: Curiously, another fix is to change `\begingroup` to `{` and `\endgroup` to `}` in the definition of `\delim`. I thought they were equivalent, but evidently I was wrong, so what is the difference between a `\begingroup…\endgroup` pair and a brace wrapping?

Comment: @MickG don't ask new questions in comments `{}` and `\begingroup\endgroup` are completely different in math (and in alignments) and an ams alignment is a an alignment in math...  `{}` forms a new math list and returns a mathord atom `\begingroup` affects the grouping without making a new list or math atom, you can (with care) have an unmatched `\begingroup` in an alignment cell, but you can't have an unmatched `{` as the `&` will not be taken as cell end if it is at a different brace level